# Ayuda con sistema de votación vuejs firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Estoy empezando con esto, así que quizá lo que propongo sea una auténtica chapuza, mil perdones de ante mano.

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de votaciones (típico upvote/downvote sobre el mismo botón (tipo el Fav de twitter)) y después de darle un millón de vueltas, se me ocurrió hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

**contexto**: de momento, tengo un crud con vuejs y firebase, donde un usuario registrado, puede crear un post (item):

1) Al item le he añadido una propiedad: "upvoted" que toma un valor *false* al momento de crearse

2) luego he añadido dos métodos (uno para votar y otro para desvotar)

3) he añadido un operador ternario donde (al menos la idea) es, comprobar el valor que tiene "upvoted" (true o false) y en función de eso, ejecutar la primera o la segunda función

**el componente completo**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul v-for="item in items" class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="d-flex list-group-item p-3">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between pl-1 pr-2 pt-1 pb-1">
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <img style="width: 25px; height: 25px; border-radius: 4px;" :src=item.itemAvatar>
                            <span class="ml-1">@{{ item.itemName }}</span>
                        </span>
                        <div>
                            <small class="badge badge-light font-weight-normal">{{ item.itemTopic }}</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                        <small>{{ item.itemDescription }}</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <small><i class="far fa-comment"></i>{{ item.comments }}</small>
                        <button @click="item.upvoted ? downvoteitem(item.id, item.upvotes) : upvoteitem(item.id, item.upvotes)" class="ml-auto btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-upvote"> {{ item.upvotes }}</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
    import itemCard from './itemCard.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            itemCard,
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapState(['userProfile', 'currentUser', 'items', 'users']),
        },
        methods: {
            upvoteitem(itemId, upvotes) {
                let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}_${itemId}`
                fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).get().then(doc => {
                    if (doc.exists) { return }
                    fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).set({
                        itemId: itemId,
                        userId: this.currentUser.uid
                    }).then(() => {
                        // update item upvotes
                        fb.itemsCollection.doc(itemId).update({
                            upvotes: upvotes + 1,
                            upvoted: true
                        })
                    })
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            },
            downvoteitem(itemId, upvotes) {
                let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}_${itemId}`
                fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).get().then(doc => {
                    if (doc.exists) { return }
                    fb.upvotesCollection.doc(docId).remove({
                        itemId: itemId,
                        userId: this.currentUser.uid
                    }).then(() => {
                        // update item upvotes
                        fb.itemsCollection.doc(itemId).update({
                            upvotes: upvotes - 1,
                            upvoted: false
                        })
                    })
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Pero no funciona bien. He comprobado que con el primer click se ejecuta la primera función y el valor de "upvoted" cambia pero, una vez clickado, ya no se ejecuta ninguna función (se queda con un 1 o un -1)

Comment: Me parece que te falta cambiar item.upvoted en algun lado??

Comment: Mil gracias por contestar! Pues, en principio (no sé si bien) está debajo de upvotes: upvotes +1 y upvotes -1

Comment: eso en la base de datos.. y en tu modelo vue donde cambia?

Comment: en tu data esta upvoted.. ese valor en algun momento, cambio??? de donde viene item.upvoted?? no esta en tu data?

Comment: te refieres a poner algo tipo: export default { data() { return { upvoted: false } } y luego en la función, fuera de lo que "afecta" a firebase, un this.updated = !this.updated? (acabo de intentarlo, pero no me funciona, debo estar haciendo algo mal), mil gracias igualmente

Comment: Tu problema no es firebase, es VUE... mostra tu componente por favor...

Comment: Sí, lo puse en una respuesta abajo, no me cabía por aquí. Saludos @gbianchi

Comment: No. Una edicion a tu pregunta debe ir en tu pregunta. Usa el boton [edit] y agrega la informacion ahi. y borra esa respuesta.

Comment: Hecho @gbianchi, muchas gracias por decirme cómo debía ponerlo

Comment: Perfecto. Veo que estas usando vuex... veo la actualizacion en firebase, pero en ningun momento veo una actualizacion a tu store. Estoy casi seguro que te falta eso. Tenas algun action o mutation que falte?